# Error creating WebGL context во всех браузерах

Tags: windows-7, браузер, webgl, radeon, ati

WebGL отказывается работать на компьютере. Пробовал разные браузеры, проверял на различных сайтах, например, [здесь](http://adamferriss.com/gush/)

Пишет:

> "It doesn't appear your computer can support WebGL."

Браузеры обновлены. Драйвер на видеокарту обновлен.
Результат тот же. В чем может быть причина?

Видео: ATI Radeon HD 3600 Series
Пробовал браузеры: Opera, Google Chrome, Firefox.
ОС: Windows 7.

Кстати, месяц назад все работало.

Comment: @Пашка Бордюгов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы пользуетесь *Google Chrome*, то запустите его с параметром `--ignore-gpu-blacklist`. Чтобы определить этот параметр, правой кнопкой мышки кликните на значке браузера Chrome и выберите пункт **Properties** (Свойства) в контекстном меню. Добавьте обозначенный параметр в конец командной строки в поле **Target** (Объект). После этого Chrome всегда будет запускаться с данным параметром.

Если вы пользуетесь браузером *Firefox*, введите в адресной строке `about:config`. Браузер выведет предупреждение: "*This might void your warranty!*" ("Будьте осторожны, а то лишитесь гарантии!"). Щёлкните на кнопке "*I'll be careful, I promise!*" ("Я обещаю, что буду осторожен!"). Введите `webgl` в текстовое поле с подписью **Search** (Поиск) или **Filter** (Фильтр), после чего Firefox оставит в списке только параметры, имеющие отношение к WebGL. Дважды щёлкните на параметре **webgl.force-enabled**, чтобы его значение изменилось с `false` на `true`.